# Font displayed differently in PDF and HTML

Tags: html, pdf, fonts, itext

I am currently working on a web app to convert HTML to PDF (I am using iTextSharp to convert). 
I have noticed a problem with the fonts though. When I generate a font with 12px in HTML and in PDF, the display is different. The fonts in PDF looks bigger.

I'd like the HTML to be the closest possible to PDF, is there a way to have similar display?
And why is the font so much bigger in PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `.em` and `.pt` instead of just `.px`

```
p{font-size:1em}
p{font-size:1pt}
p{font-size:1px}
```

Also try adding `line-spacing`. The *iTextSharp*:

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("span", "size", "1em");
styles.LoadTagStyle("span", "size", "1pt");
styles.LoadTagStyle("span", "size", "1px");
```

Comment: It seems like the problem came from the fact that the unit in PDF was pt. I just had to change the html to pt for the size to match.
Thanks!

Comment: @gapan No problem this is often the issue. Adobe does with Photoshop too.